What is the purpose of the A Maj chord in the key of B Maj
Referring to this video, at 1:10, I see that in the accompaniment, the left hand goes from Ab to A. I'm trying to understand what is the purpose of this chord in the progression.
I think it would have some relation to modal interchange, but I don't see A Maj in either the parallel or relative minor of the key of B Maj. What would be the accurate relationship of this chord and the progression be in this context?
Additionally, is there a pattern I can infer from such a progression that can help me identify opportunities to use this sort of progression? Instinctively, I had used a diatonic E Maj (IV) > F# Maj (V) progression, instead of A Maj > F# Maj as shown in the video.

In the parallel key of B minor, there exists the chord of A major.
So, that's where the theory makes it fit. It's a very oft used chord in any key - ♭VII as it's known.
I often refer to it as IV/IV, but that's not always how folk see it.

Thanks! Turns out I was thinking of the B harmonic minor scale, which didn't have A Maj. I'm trying to identify when I could use this type of progression, especially for playing by ear, would you be able to provide some examples or indications such as mood or chord quality to listen out for to potentially identify such an interchange?

So many pop type songs have this sequence - Bm A G F#, or Bm A E A for starters.

@YongYunJing The harmonic scale is just one way of using the minor mode; and it's not the default one, even if it's the common one. In fact, the minor mode, by default, is just the scale built upon the 6th grade of the major mode (Aeolian): the A major chord is exactly the dominant chord of D major and the natural seventh grade chord of B minor. The seventh grade of a minor scale is not the leading tone in its common sense (half step to the tonic), so, in B minor, unless specified, it never is A#, but A; and the A chord of B minor (as in all seventh chords of minor scales) is major.

@YongYunJing If you're in B minor, then I think it makes the most sense to think of A as the dominant of its relative D major. It even tends to often work pretty much like a dominant in tunes. (See, for instance, Lady in Black, which only contains two chords: Ami and G. G effectively works like the dominant there.)
